# How to fire multiple async calls in koa using generators+promises

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise, generator, koa

I'm new to generators and having a hard time finding an example of how to fire off multiple async calls with generators + native promises

so far I have in a sudo code format

```
function *getData (){
var data = yeild makeAPICall ();
}

function makeAPICall (){
  async code
  return async code
}
```

How would I structure my code if I wanted to make multiple calls to makeAPICall in parallel using native javascript promises.

Comment: Aww, the duplicate really is a totally different question, though it asks for exactly the same thing (how to parallelise promise execution in generators) - you couldn't have found it.

Comment: I think it's kind of a stretch to mark this as a duplicate as the context is different ie a koajs app which uses the co library, vs bluebird.  I think answering this question would be more helpful then having to look at the other question and trying to figure out how it relates to this question. not a big deal, just my $0.02.

Comment: The "duplicate" answer includes how to use native generators not co and using the bluebird library not native javascript promises.